# what value should be passed in the where clause to ignore it

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

How can we omit a where condition in mysql.

```
SELECT * FROM demo where name = 'xyz';
```

In the above example what value should pass in "name" attribute so that where clause can be ignored.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not simply remove the clause?

Comment: If you want the where clause to be ignored why not just remove it?

Comment: Can you include your application code?  Are you using PHP?

Comment: @Nico Haase & d0little Actually, there are multiple conditions written in the where clause. For one scenario i don't  want a particular condition to be executed. Ex:(query): SELECT * FROM demo where name = 'xyz' and id=123 and phone=6787678;  So, in the given example i want to ignore or comment phone attribute.

Comment: Then why not remove that condition from the query if you don't need it?

Answer (score 1):

If `'xyz'` is a parameter, then a typical method would be to pass in `NULL` and use logic like this:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM demo d
WHERE d.name = :name OR :name IS NULL;
```

`:name` is the parameter you are passing in.

Comment: I think this will return either those record which has matching "name" parameter or those which has null value.

Comment: @UjjwalChauhan . . . No.  This returns all rows if the parameter is `NULL`.  It returns matching rows if the parameter is not `NULL`.